# How to get findElementById method?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I loaded Selenium latest version 3.3.1 to my system through maven dependencies. While trying to code, I couldn't get the method `findElementById()`. Instead, I am getting only old method `findElement()`. Can anyone help me?
Note: In maven, it shows only latest version.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

add following dependency to maven, do maven clean and maven build

- Use RemoteWebDriver type while instantiating  driver like
  "RemoteWebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()" as RemoteWebDriver class has 
  findElementById() method

  ```
    < dependency>
    < groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    < artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    < version>3.3.1</version>
   </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method from the class By:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element id"))
```

Comment: I know that. But in latest version we have durect methid findElementById(). I want to get that

Answer (score 0):

It depends on language you are using for your automation:

For Java:

```
driver().findElement(By.id("locator")).click();
```

For Python:

```
driverInstance.find_element_by_id("Id Locator").click()
```